# How do you define and inject a bean with annotations in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

My bean definition looks like this:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter { 
    @Bean
    public ExecutorService executorService() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }   
}
```

I want to use this bean in another class like this:

```
@Endpoint
public class SOAPEndpoint {
    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executor;
}
```

Is that actually correct? I'm curious because the output says that the injected instance has a pool size of 0 instead of 5.

```
System.out.println(executor);
```

> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1058b8a[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]